# Marquee for LinearLayout

Tags: android, layout

My Android app uses a ListView where each row contains many elements: a LinearLayout contains a TextView, ImageView, TextView, ImageView and so on.

My problem is that this layout can extend out of view (i.e. run off the screen).

Is it possible to set a marquee to the LinearLayout? Or should i use something like animation? I have not worked with animations until now.

Comment: Its not possible..im 200% sure

Comment: Thank you guys for your help.
I think i make a animation instead of marquee. I found a good site which explaine animations very simple. http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/06/android-development-more-animations-part-1/

Comment: hi,do you found solution for this question?

Answer (score 0):

Generally if it a normal `TextView`  android:ellipsize="marquee"

and in `oncreate()` writing `tv.setSelected(true);` should make it a marquee text. donno if it is in `list view`

Comment: The part in my list row which i want to marquee is not only a text view. I want to slide a complete LinearLayout which is one part in my row.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is a scrollview over your view.  Just make scrollview only has one child (like a linearlayout).

Comment: This is one solution but i want the slide automaticaly and not by hand.